# Docker compose network issue only on server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm trying to configure a docker compose to connect a nodejs application (with nest) on another container with postgres.
From local it work properly, but when trying it on the server it doesn't work, its like postgres container not accept connection.

```yaml
services:
  fe:
    image: "feimage-dockerhub"
    ports:
      - 4800:80
  api:
    image: "apiimage-dockerhub"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpass
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - HOST_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - BCRYPT_SALT=10
    restart: always
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dbname
      POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dbpass
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

I've tried running two container and put them togheter in the same network, but connection goes to timetout too, with ping to postgres service it reply correctly.

Maybe it would be usefull to know that server has installed portainer, and other stack with quite similar configuration works without problems.

Maybe I'm missing something

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.2
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.7
 Git commit:        569dd73
 Built:             Mon Mar 27 16:16:30 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.2
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.7
  Git commit:       219f21b
  Built:            Mon Mar 27 16:16:30 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20
  GitCommit:        2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5
  GitCommit:        v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Thanks

I've tried a simple configuration to check comunication between container using psql to connect from a postgres host to another and it worked only locally, on server same issues

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: vault
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
  db2:
    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: vault
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
```

EDIT

I've opened servers ports and exposed postgres port and it worked, but I don't want db exposed on, it seems like a issue for docker network only

Comment: Please show your code using in your `api` service. Maybe something wrongs in code!

Comment: There is one answer to show code, thanks

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something on server (I'm not expert), but everything works well in my machine, on server with portainer or with docker-compose not.
I've tried two container with postgres and put them on the same network, but still not works, and container cannot reach each other

Answer (score 0):

This is the part to configure database connection

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSourceOptions, EntitySchema } from 'typeorm';

export function typeOrmConfig(
  entities: EntitySchema[] = [],
  migrations: string[] = [],
): TypeOrmModuleOptions & Partial<DataSourceOptions> {
  console.log(process.env)
  const res: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    synchronize: true,
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    dropSchema:
      process.env.DROP_SCHEMA === undefined
        ? false
        : Boolean(process.env.DROP_SCHEMA),
    migrationsTableName: '__migrations__',
    migrations,
    entities,
  };

  if (process.env.POSTGRES_PORT) {
    return {
      ...res,
      port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT
        ? Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT)
        : 5432,
    };
  }
  return res;
}
```

This is what print from process.env

```
{
  JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME: '100000000000000',
  NODE_VERSION: '18.18.0',
  HOSTNAME: '30bd4fc3d1af',
  ENV_FILE: 'prod',
  YARN_VERSION: '1.22.19',
  HOME: '/root',
  HOST_URL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  BCRYPT_SALT: '10',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'dbpass',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
  POSTGRES_HOST: 'db',
  POSTGRES_USER: 'dbuser',
  PWD: '/usr/app',
  POSTGRES_DB: 'dbname',
  POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
}
```

Anyway connection not working using psql -h ... too, it goes to timeout

Comment: Hi, this isn't an answer, but some added content to your original question. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you